# Binding WPF Image.Source from https when files are hosted on a shared drive

Tags: wpf, https, proxy, system.net

I have a WPF app with `<Image Source="{Binding myUrl}">` that displays images retrieved from an https address.

I've configured the proxy in the .config as such:

```
   <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy bypassonlocal="true"
            proxyaddress="http://ourProxy:8080/" />
    </defaultProxy>
```

When the application is hosted on my machine and executed everything displays fine.

However, if I store an exact copy of the application and its configuration files on a shared drive (within our domain) and execute it on my machine the images no longer appear.

Is this some kind of trust/permissions thing?  How can I get the images to show (or, i assume, allow the https connection) when executing from the shared drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a console app to test http connections, turns out the problem is with the defaultProxy setting app.config.

This specific issue and its fix is noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327691/exception-when-specifying-defaultproxy-in-app-config-when-running-net4-0-applica).